# Problems with installing with disks

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, live-cd, disk, cd

So I have a 64 Bit Computer so I downloaded the Ubuntu 64 Bit ISO.

Well I have some 700MB CD-R disk. And I do not have a USB that is available to be used.
My question is can I break the ISO down to smaller sizes and put it on multiple disks?

And I do hate using Lubuntu so can someone please help me?

P.S. where I am right now has no stores nearby so I can't go and buy any DVD-R disks.

Comment: I would recommend that you get a USB flash drive, or a DVD disc.

Comment: Like I said "I do not have a USB that is available to be used."

and

"P.S. where I am right now has no stores nearby so I can't go and buy any DVD-R disks."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have another Computer you may be able to use it as a network installation server.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LocalNet

This is not a simple process but it is a way to install ubuntu without a USB drive or Disc.

Comment: Do the computers need to both have an internet connection?

Comment: I have never done an install this way myself. I plan on doing so for a learning experience when i find the time..... From what I understand so far you will need the ubuntu Desktop ISO you would like to install, and  a copy of ubuntu server that will deliver the  installation to your PC. The Ubuntu server ISO should fit on one of your CDs its around 500MB in size you will likely not need the internet for the installation itself but to get server configured you will need to install some additional packages.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I might use this technique if all else fails. Because I am going to use and SD card to transfer it.

Comment: you have an SD card? you might be able to use that to install ubuntu with. a usb drive and a SD are close to the same thing you might be able to turn that SD into bootable media.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can open ISO file with some archiver program and delete something from it. What can be deleted, however,without installation fail -  is for you to guess.

Comment: That could work but I would rather keep all of the files.

Comment: Then how do you expect to make the image smaller while retaining all of its content? Do you have a 4-dimensional CD burner?

Comment: Nope But I found another way with an SD card.